# How to handle deep linking in react native / expo

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, expo

I have posted about this previously but still struggling to get a working version.

I want to create a sharable link from my app to a screen within my app and be able to pass through an ID of sorts.

I have a link on my home screen opening a link to my expo app with 2 parameters passed through as a query string

```
const linkingUrl = 'exp://192.168.0.21:19000';

...

_handleNewGroup = async () => {
  try {
    const group_id = await this.createGroupId()
    Linking.openURL(`${linkingUrl}?screen=camera&group_id=${group_id}`);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(`Unable to create group ${err}`)
  }
};
```

Also in my home screen I have a handler that gets the current URL and extracts the query string from it and navigates to the camera screen with a `group_id` set

```
async handleLinkToCameraGroup(){  
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    let queryString = url.replace(linkingUrl, '');
    if (queryString) {
      const data = qs.parse(queryString);
      if(data.group_id) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Camera', {group_id: data.group_id});
      } 
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

Several issues with this:

1. Once linked to the app with the query string set, the values don't get reset so they are always set and therefore `handleLinkToCameraGroup` keeps running and redirecting.
2. Because the URL is not an http formatted URL, it is hard to extract the query string. Parsing the query string returns this:

   {
     "?screen": "camera",
     "group_id": "test",
   }
3. It doesn't seem right having this logic in the home screen. Surely this should go in the app.js file. But this causes complications not being able to use `Linking` because the `RootStackNavigator` is a child of app.js so I do not believe I can navigate from this file?

Any help clarifying the best approach to deep linking would be greatly appreciated.